# Making "function arguments" consisting of comma separated arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function, argument-passing, array-intersect

I am having problems in PHP creating functional arguments made up of arrays separated by commas, for example I want to automate the use of the `array_intersect` function.

The function accepts multiple arrays separated by comma's as its function arguments. E.g.:

```
array_intersect($setarray1, $setarray2, $setarray3, ...)
```

I have hundreds of different array's to process in the `array_intersect` function (i.e I may pass 3, 4 of 5 arrays to the function at a time).

My question is, how do I create a function argument made up of comma separated arrays that I can then pass to the `array_intersect` function?

Here is an example of some test data

```
$setsarray[]=array('all','0'            ,'0&1','0&2','0&3');
$setsarray[]=array('all'    ,'1'        ,'0&1'            ,'1&2','1&3');
$setsarray[]=array('all'        ,'2'          ,'0&2'      ,'1&2'      ,'2&3');
$setsarray[]=array('all'            ,'3'            ,'0&3'      ,'1&3','2&3');

$setnumb=count($setsarray);
```

Manually I can do this...

```
$vennGraph['all']=array_intersect(
$setsarray[$setnumb-4],$setsarray[$setnumb-3], $setsarray[$setnumb-2]
);
```

The function arguments are **array comma array comma array** e.t.c.
So I want to to generate **$vennGraph['Again_and_Again']=array_intersect("put my content here");**

I have been reading through the responses (thankyou!) and they sound promising but I am still dumb struck! BTW, I am using PHP Version 5.3.10

ps would it be easier if I put commas into the $setsarray as shown below?

```
$setsarray[]=array('all','0'            ,'0&1','0&2','0&3');
$setsarray[]= ',';
$setsarray[]=array('all'    ,'1'        ,'0&1'            ,'1&2','1&3');
$setsarray[]= ',';
$setsarray[]=array('all'        ,'2'          ,'0&2'      ,'1&2'      ,'2&3');
$setsarray[]= ',';
$setsarray[]=array('all'            ,'3'            ,'0&3'      ,'1&3','2&3');
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods depending on your PHP version:

1. [The "..." token method](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list.new) which is only possible in PHP 5.6 and later
2. [func_num_args(), func_get_arg() and func_get_args() functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list.old) for older versions of PHP

Comment: `func_*_args` offers no equivalent for *calling* a function with variable argument lists though.

Comment: I have had a play and this seams to be getting somewhere, thanks for your comments and I will have a look at @deceze suggestions also.....  `code $inter = function() {
 return array_intersect(func_get_arg(0), func_get_arg(3));
};
print_r(call_user_func_array($inter, $setsarray)); `

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong, you cannot concatenate arrays with commas, pass them to a function and make the function see them as separate arguments. If you write `foo($bar)`, there's only one argument passed to `foo`, regardless of how many commas might be in `$bar`.

What you're looking for is [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array), into which you can pass an array of arrays which will be received as separate arguments by the function. PHP 5.6+ offers some syntactic sugar around this in the form of [variable length argument lists](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list).